# Lightdm gives black screen after logging out

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, login, lightdm, logout

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with lightdm.

Everything is fine except that if I log out, the screen turns black. And I have to press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2` to get the console and issue `sudo lightdm` to get the login screen.

Two further observations:

1. This problem goes away if I switch to gdm3. But I require lightdm to use x11vnc.
2. I am using nvidia-driver-450. I tried several versions of nvidia driver; the problem persists. If I remove the driver, then the problem goes away. But I need the nvidia driver for my work.

Any idea how to fix this problem is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1362536/134205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials, I found the following command solves the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session ubuntu-desktop
```

I bumped into this solution here which may have more useful details for others: [can't start lightdm without systemctl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721870/cant-start-lightdm-without-systemctl)