# Nvidia proprietary driver suddenly crashes computer

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I'm experiencing issues with my Nvidia videocard. I'm using proprietary driver 'coz
I'm having rendering problems when using the open source driver.
The proprietary driver is tested as it says in the system. And it used to work fine.
I even got Nvidia sw as soon as the driver was selected. However I don't know
if Ubuntu released some updates but the computer won't boot if I select the tested
driver and reboot. I get just black screen and that's it.

Can anyone confirm using Nvidia videocard with proprietary driver and what release of Ubuntu you're using ? I don't mind going for alternative release.

Comment: Possibly related: [elementary SO](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/28776/19079), [Ubuntu bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-restricted-modules-hwe-5.11/+bug/1943086).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the older nvidia drivers in 20.04 crash the computer.

In 20.10 upwards and the newest drivers this problem doesn't happen (prob. why I **had** to upgrade.)

I don't know what Ubuntu version you are using... But the NVidia Driver 700 should work (well for Ubuntu 21.04 and NVIDIA GeForce 1660 super)

I didn't get render problems, just poor performance with the noveau driver

You might want to install the newest driver using the graphical interface (additional drivers) but it also should work by installing this packet:  `nvidia-driver-700`

apt automatically installs dependencies. To install the packet I recommend to use `apt` and not `apt-get` because apt is just newer

Comment: My videocard is Nvidia M600M which is low-end videocard. Ubuntu's driver is 470 and when I ran `apt install nvidia-driver-470` it said the driver is up to date. No newer drivers. But if I select the driver and reboot the computer will crash. I'm recalling only last month it worked fine. 2 days ago I had to reinstall Ubuntu and the driver is unusable all of the sudden.

Comment: I'm on 20.04 as the tag says.

Comment: If I would be a game developer I would be completely screwed just 'coz Ubuntu released driver update and can't use videocard properly now.

Comment: sry but yes now IK

Comment: you might really have to use 21.04 - also check your logs. And try to reinstall the driver, try another kernel (xanmod 2 kernel) ...